# Vue js dynamically loaded component name from ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, vuejs2

I am new in vuejs . I want to load component from ajax response.

```
<div id="app"></div>
export default(){
  created: function(){
    const url = "xyz.json";
    this.$http.get(url).then(response => {
      this.resp = response.body;
      var comp = this.resp.components;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my JSON response

```
{
   components: "Hello.vue",

}
```

I want to draw dynamically components by using json data

**Update:**
My Purpose is to draw a vuejs component in response of server side data. In server side data, I will tell which component will be loaded for this particular action. For example, I want to render particular view in response of drop-down value. If value is 1 , then server will tell load A component, if value is 2, then server will tell load B component.

Comment: Is not clear what do you want to do, try to better explain your problem.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: You can use [Routing](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/routing.html) if you have many components, or use v-if or v-show to display only what you want.